# How to get a list of area names from geo coding

Tags: php, android, google-maps

Iam getting a area name from geo coding my code is.

```
 $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$latitude.','.$longitude.'&sensor=false');
```

can i give here list of lat and long instead of one lat and long because i have a 700 points and geo coding taking too much time to compute.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy my friend. first of all read the response from your url. ... it will return you the json then use the following code to run

```
public static String getAddress(JSONObject result) {
    if (result.has("results")) {
        try {
            JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("results");
            if (array.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject place = array.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray components = place.getJSONArray("address_components");
                for (int i = 0; i < components.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject component = components.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray types = component.getJSONArray("types");
                    for (int j = 0; j < types.length(); j++) {
                        if (types.getString(j).equals("route")) {
                            return component.getString("long_name");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

In my current code, i am parsing it for the specific routes .... just skip the condition and save the result in your Data structure object

Comment: but how i give list of lat lng to get array of addresses can u please tell me or give me the line.